# Industry Standard for storing SQL Server connection data for remote applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2, connection-string, usage-statistics

We recently ran into an issue where we were forced to change our Read/Write account password for our SQL server database. The result has been an epic treasure hunt to identify all the web applications and macros that were tracking usage data(and backend data to support the app) to the database - and then updating each individual connection string.

Surely there must be a way of storing a central connection string so that it's secure but accessable by multiple applications? We were thinking about js, which would work for the read-only account but obviously not a good idea to have the read/write account username and password freely available.

Notes: All connection attempts to the database will be on a secure intranet.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281463/centralised-database-connection-string-provider, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382690/is-there-a-way-to-store-connection-strings-in-a-central-location-other-than-mach, and so on. Search for ".net centralized configuration" or simply use integrated security, so the account who runs an application determines what data sources they can access, not some username/password string in some config file.

Comment: Have you seen this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26364065/iis-web-config-same-file-for-multiple-websites

Comment: For finding connection strings, how about a regular expression finder? Sublime Text Editor has a Find In Files and Agent Ransack has been a godsend as well.

Comment: yeah been through the regex find and replace option. The problem is that we have 100's of folders, some have web apps, some not so it takes hours to run